# How to convert execution time to a specific format?

Tags: date-format, ssrs-2008

I am working on a report that allows people to print off data for physical signatures.  Part of the requirement is to format the exectuion date in the format DDMONYY (27Aug12).  I can not find a way to set the format of the date in the report.

How can I format the report exectuion time to the format DDMONYY?

Comment: Try the `Format` property..?

Comment: @jonseigel I tried that, but I couldn't find any information online that was useful and what I tried was completely wrong (it was coming out as the number of the week).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this article: [Working with Dates in Reporting Services](http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/04/10/working-with-dates-in-reporting-services/)

I can't test right now, but try this: `=Format(Cdate(Parameters!Date.Value),"ddMMMyy")`